# Using model method inside controller in Rails,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model, Photo, which has, as part of its business logic, a workflow state where a user can reject or approve its submission. The act of approving or rejecting was originally split into two methods.

For example

```
  def toggle_reject_field
    @entry.reject!
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to request.referer }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js
    end    
  end
```

and the link_to path

```
%td= link_to "Reject", (toggle_reject_field_admin_entry_path(photo, params.except(:controller, :action))), :remote => true
```

I want to make these two methods one, so  that the link_to is like

```
 %td= link_to "Approve", toggle_field_admin_entry_path(photo, params.except(:controller, :action))
```

and the method is something like this

```
      def toggle_field
        @entry.toggle_state
        redirect_to pending_admin_entries_path
      end
```

with the method 'toggle_state' residing in my Photo model (pleas note that despite the model being called photo, the instances of Photo are called 'entry')

```
  def toggle_state
    self.state = (self.state == 'approve') ? 'reject' : 'approve'
  end
```

here be my routes too

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :entries do
      get :toggle_field, on: :member
      get :pending, on: :collection
      get :approved, on: :collection
      get :rejected, on: :collection
    end 
  end
```

however i get this error, which I assume means the method 'toggle_state' according to the controller, doesnt exist?

```
undefined method `toggle_state' for nil:NilClass
 def toggle_field
    @entry.toggle_state
    redirect_to pending_admin_entries_path
  end
```

help would be massively appreciated, I feel as though I have been banging my head against the wall for along time with this one...

Rico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@entry` variable is `nil`. I guess you have `before_filter` method to find `@entry` record, but you don't apply it before `toggle_field` action.

Comment: @MarkLipka oh my, thank you so much!, although I still encounter this error undefined method `state' for #<Photo:0x007f992428fd10>. I assumed that in my model method I am defining the state by use of ternary operator?

Comment: @rico_mac Is there a state field? Did you run all your migrations?

Comment: man, I am sorry, thanks for your help, its because the method called should have been 'workflow_state'. You saved me hours, thank you